# public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException

Tags: java

Всем привет. Я плохо знаю Java (только пол-недели изучаю). Изучаю по книге Герберта Шилдта. У меня вопрос по поводу throws java.io.IOException. В книге сказано, что его надо вписывать после метода main. Но метод main как я понял используется для старта программы. Что использовать вместо метода main (я про случай,  когда System.in.read() используется не в начале программы). Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не понял в чём проблема, throws java.io.IOException пиши в любом методе, в смысле где вызываешь System.in.read(). Не обязательно писать после main.